# How can i install OpenBLAS and numpy on windows10 and anaconda?

Tags: python, numpy, theano, openblas

There are so many guide of install openBLAS for linux, So I want to know how can i install openBLAS on windows10 with anaconda3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conda 'openblas' version available. To get it use `conda install -c menpo openblas`
referenced from https://anaconda.org/menpo/openblas